# Check uniqness of data by 3 columns with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem with checking uniquness of data with PostgreSQL. I have the people table which has the following data:

```
 id | identifier | first_name | middle_name | last_name |      email      |         created_at         |         updated_at         
----+------------+------------+-------------+-----------+-----------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 | identifier | First      | A.          | Last      | some@email.com  | 2015-11-11 14:46:17.782689 | 2015-11-11 14:46:17.782689
  2 | identifier | First 2    | M.          | Last 2    | some@email2.com | 2015-11-11 14:46:17.790697 | 2015-11-11 14:46:17.790697
(2 rows)
```

Now I want to find ids of record which identifier belongs to more than one first_name - last_name combination. So in this example we have two records with the same identifier but different first and last names. I was trying to check if there any duplicates with the following sql but this does not return anything:

```
SELECT
    identifier, first_name, last_name, COUNT(*)
FROM
    people
GROUP BY
    identifier, first_name, last_name
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: You should exclude `first_name, last_name` from `select` and `group by`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `grouping`:

```
select * from people 
where identifier in(select identifier from people 
                    group by identifier
                    having count(distinct first_name) > 1 or 
                           count(distinct last_name) > 1)
```

or with `exists`:

```
select * from people p1 
where exists(select * from people p2 
             where p1.identifier = p2.identifier and
                   (p1.first_name <> p2.first_name or p1.last_name <> p2.last_name))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want duplicate *identifiers*:

```
select identifer
from people p
group by identifer
having count(*) > 1;
```

If you want identifiers where the name is different:

```
select identifer
from people p
group by identifer
having min(first_name) <> max(first_name) or
       min(last_name) <> max(last_name);
```

(or:  `having count(distinct first_name, last_name) > 1`.)

If you want the original rows, I would use window functions:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             min(first_name) over (partition by identifer) as minfn,
             max(first_name) over (partition by identifer) as maxfn,
             min(last_name) over (partition by identifer) as minln,
             min(last_name) over (partition by identifer) as maxln,
      from people
     ) p
where minfn <> maxfn or minln <> maxln;
```

This would be easier if Postgres supported `count(distinct)` as a window function.